# Ubuntu 16.04 cannot start Installer

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 on a workstation in my office. I have a created a usb-image using `dd` on my laptop.

After choosing the boot device,  the screen shows different options that I have (install/try etc..)

Once I choose an option, the screen essentially goes blank with a small cursor that is blinking.

So far I have tried adding the `nomodeset` switch to the kernel bootline. This results in my monitor giving the "out of sync" message.

With the `quiet` and `splash` things removed. The screen hangs with the following message:

[image: screenshot]

Also, the workstation has two nvidia gtx 1080 cards in it. The monitor is plugged to the first one using a hdmi cable.